# React-Native Picker wheel for Views

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

Like the title says I would like to create something like the Picker but instead of scrolling between text I would like to be able to scroll between cards that are View components. Is there a way to do this with the built in Picker or is there a npm packet somewhere which achieve this effect?

My code with Picker that is not working and only displaying the label

```
    <View>
        <Text>{this.state.language}</Text>
        <Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.language}
            style={{ height: 250, width: "100%",}}
            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
            <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java">
                <View>
                    <Text>HELLO THERE GENERAL KENOBI</Text>
                </View>
            </Picker.Item>
            <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
        </Picker>
    </View>
```

This is somewhat the effect I would like to achieve, being able to scroll between cards

[image]